# Plotly.express Area multiple plots data error

Tags: pandas, plotly, background-image, plotly-python, area

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
df={'x':[1,2,3,4,5],'y1':[1,2,3,4,5],'y2':[2,3,4,5,6],'y3':[3,4,5,6,7]}
df=pd.DataFrame(df)
fig = px.area(df, x="x", y=['y1','y2','y3'])
fig.show()
```

As you can see my Y data are maximum 7. Why the results in the figure shows wrong values?
[Why the results in the figure shows wrong values?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87ZkS.png)

Answer (score 1):

#### Short answer:

Just add the following to your setup to obtain the desired behavior of `px.area`:

```
fig.update_traces(stackgroup = None, fill = 'tozeroy')
```

#### The details:

`px.area` produces a stacked area chart through the trace attribute [`stackgroup`](https://plotly.com/python/filled-area-plots/#stacked-area-chart) which by default is set to `'one'`. To obtain what you're requesting here, you can update this attribute to `None` with:

```
fig.update_traces(stackgroup = None)
```

#### Plot 1 - Unstacked traces

[image]

As you can see, this will display the values in the way you're requesting, but that won't help you that much since the area fill colors are missing. By default, the `fill` attribute for the traces are set to `tonexty`. Other options are:

```
['none', 'tozeroy', 'tozerox', 'tonexty', 'tonextx', 'toself', 'tonext']
```

And if you set `fill` to `tozeroy` with `fig.update_traces(fill = 'tozeroy')` you'll get what you're looking for:

#### Plot 2 - Almost there, but what's up with the colors?

[image]

This is going to look a bit strange for your particular dataset since the resulting areas will cover each other all the way and because the area colors are opaque. But you can see by the colors of the legend that the color setup is still the same as in your plot. You can verify this by using the following dataset:

```
df={'x':[1,2,3,4,5],'y1':[1,2,3,4,5],'y2':[2,3,4,5,2],'y3':[3,4,5,6,1]}
```

#### Plot 3 - Bingo!

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
# df={'x':[1,2,3,4,5],'y1':[1,2,3,4,5],'y2':[2,3,4,5,6],'y3':[3,4,5,6,7]}
df={'x':[1,2,3,4,5],'y1':[1,2,3,4,5],'y2':[2,3,4,5,2],'y3':[3,4,5,6,1]}
df=pd.DataFrame(df)
fig = px.area(df, x="x", y=['y1','y2','y3'])

#fig.update_traces(stackgroup = None)
#fig.update_traces(fill = 'tozeroy')
fig.update_traces(stackgroup = None, fill = 'tozeroy')
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

`plotly.express.area` creates a *stacked* area plot, where each filled area corresponds to one column of the input data: https://plotly.com/python/filled-area-plots/

For example, at `x = 5`, the stacked area plot reaches `y = 18 = 5 + 6 + 7`.

To show each column's data series as-is, without stacking (i.e., starting from the y-coordinate of zero):

```
fig = px.line(df, x='x', y=['y1', 'y2', 'y3'])
```

Comment: Thanks @Peter for response. You made the problem clear for me.

What if I need to fill the area under the each line like area?

Comment: I'm actually not sure, beyond looping through each column and building a separate area plot for each DataFrame column.